# Processing Times

Tags: labor

Are Processing Times accessible via your API?
https://icert.doleta.gov/#fragment-2

Comment: whose api? whose processing times? this is not a government site...

Comment: @albert, is this an issue with the [labor] tag that maybe needs special cases? I agree the question is too vague.

Comment: @marcusD i think that is part of it. i think government agencies blanket pointing their users here as a resource is another part. i think it all can be fixed through better coordination.